# Extract prediction band from lme fit

Tags: r, prediction, confidence-interval, mixed-models

I have following model

```
x  <- rep(seq(0, 100, by=1), 10)
y  <- 15 + 2*rnorm(1010, 10, 4)*x + rnorm(1010, 20, 100)
id <- NULL
for(i in 1:10){ id <- c(id, rep(i,101)) }
dtfr <- data.frame(x=x,y=y, id=id)
library(nlme)
with(dtfr, summary(     lme(y~x, random=~1+x|id, na.action=na.omit)))
model.mx <- with(dtfr, (lme(y~x, random=~1+x|id, na.action=na.omit)))
pd       <- predict( model.mx, newdata=data.frame(x=0:100), level=0)
with(dtfr, plot(x, y))
lines(0:100, predict(model.mx, newdata=data.frame(x=0:100), level=0), col="darkred", lwd=7)
```

[image]

with `predict` and `level=0` i can plot the mean population response. How can I extract and plot the 95% confidence intervals / prediction bands from the nlme object for the whole population?

Comment: good question! If in understand you try to have an equivalent of this `curve(predict(model.lm, data.frame(x=x),interval ='confidence'),add=T)` where model.lm e.g is lm(y~x)

Comment: Yes. With the lower and upper CIs.

Comment: I think even for a lm it is a chore to get it. there is `intervals .lme` function but it don't give the band confidence just one point.

Comment: `intervals` gets the CIs of the estimates/coefficients of the fits. What I need the CIs of y for any given x.

Comment: in fact ,  @ECII did you try the hard way ...I mean calculating the band by yourself..?

Comment: What do you mean "by myself"?

Comment: Read the [r-sig-mixed models FAQ](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Warning:** Read [this thread on r-sig-mixed models](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2010q2/003585.html) before doing this. Be very careful when you interpret the resulting prediction band.

From [r-sig-mixed models FAQ](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#predictions-andor-confidence-or-prediction-intervals-on-predictions) adjusted to your example:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rep(0:100,10)
y <- 15 + 2*rnorm(1010,10,4)*x + rnorm(1010,20,100)
id<-rep(1:10,each=101)

dtfr <- data.frame(x=x ,y=y, id=id)

library(nlme)

model.mx <- lme(y~x,random=~1+x|id,data=dtfr)

#create data.frame with new values for predictors
#more than one predictor is possible
new.dat <- data.frame(x=0:100)
#predict response
new.dat$pred <- predict(model.mx, newdata=new.dat,level=0)

#create design matrix
Designmat <- model.matrix(eval(eval(model.mx$call$fixed)[-2]), new.dat[-ncol(new.dat)])

#compute standard error for predictions
predvar <- diag(Designmat %*% model.mx$varFix %*% t(Designmat))
new.dat$SE <- sqrt(predvar) 
new.dat$SE2 <- sqrt(predvar+model.mx$sigma^2)

library(ggplot2) 
p1 <- ggplot(new.dat,aes(x=x,y=pred)) + 
geom_line() +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pred-2*SE2,ymax=pred+2*SE2),alpha=0.2,fill="red") +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=pred-2*SE,ymax=pred+2*SE),alpha=0.2,fill="blue") +
geom_point(data=dtfr,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
scale_y_continuous("y")
p1
```

[image: plot]

Comment: +1 for saving me the trouble of doing it or feeling guilty for not doing it. Do note (as commented in the FAQ) that this only accounts for the uncertainty of the fixed effects **conditional on the estimates** of the random-effect variances and BLUPs/conditional modes

Comment: It would be good to have a cross-reference from you FAQ to here. I remember having re-invented that wheel quite a few time.

Comment: I don't think Prof. Bates would include this in `predict.lme`, but it would be nice if some package could provide this functionality (of course with clear warnings concerning the statistical limitations in the help file).

Comment: Would any of you mind explaining a bit what happens in the `newdat` ? Is this code applicable for any number of regressors?

Comment: @Roland: I fear that Douglas Bates would switch into his critical mode and ask "What for? Are you sure your non-statistical customers correctly read the graph?". "Conditional on the estimates" is a damned ugly concept to explain to clinical researchers.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for coming back to such an old topic, but this might address a comment here:

> it would be nice if some package could provide this functionality

This functionality is included in the [ggeffects-package](http://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects), when you use `type = "re"` (which will then include the *random effect variances*, not only *residual variances*, which is - however - the same in this particular example).

```r
library(nlme)
library(ggeffects)

x  <- rep(seq(0, 100, by = 1), 10)
y  <- 15 + 2 * rnorm(1010, 10, 4) * x + rnorm(1010, 20, 100)
id <- NULL
for (i in 1:10) {
  id <- c(id, rep(i, 101))
}
dtfr <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, id = id)
m <- lme(y ~ x,
         random =  ~ 1 + x | id,
         data = dtfr,
         na.action = na.omit)

ggpredict(m, "x") %>% plot(rawdata = T, dot.alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

```r
ggpredict(m, "x", type = "re") %>% plot(rawdata = T, dot.alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>