# R - standard errors on predictions from nlme

Tags: r, prediction, mixed-models, nonlinear-functions, nlme

This question builds on [Extract prediction band from lme fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358811/extract-prediction-band-from-lme-fit) but with non-linear mixed models.

I have a dataset of response values that are grouped by "entry." I used an AIC-model selection procedure to test which type of model (linear, logarithmic, exponential, etc.) best represented the relationship between the response and predictor. Now I want to plot the fitted values for the data in each entry, and then across entries. I also want to plot the accompanying confidence band on the overall trend--see code provided on Ben Bolker's blog and the post above (I understand this is some [finesse](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2010q2/003585.html) to the interpretation but that is another post). The latter is where I'm running into problems--see this example code:

```
#Load nlme
library(nlme)

#Create data frame
set.seed(6)
df=data.frame(y=c(1:5+runif(5,0,1),21:25+runif(5,1,5)),
              x=rep(1:5,2),entry=rep(letters[1:2],each=5))

#Group data by entry
df=groupedData(y~x|entry,data=df)

#Build model
mod=nlme(y~a+b*x,fixed=a+b~1,random=~a+b~1,start=c(a=1,b=1),data=df)

#Create data frame for predictions
pred=do.call(rbind,lapply(rownames(coef(mod)),function(i) {
  data.frame(x=seq(0.1,max(df[df$entry==i,"x"]),0.1),entry=i) } ) )
#Grab coefficients from model for a and b
a=coef(mod)[match(pred$entry,rownames(coef(mod))),1]
b=coef(mod)[match(pred$entry,rownames(coef(mod))),2]
#Grab fixed coefficients for overall trend and fitted values for individual entries using a and b above
pred$fixed=fixef(mod)[1]+fixef(mod)[2]*pred$x 
pred$fitted=a+pred$x*b

#Get SEs on predictions using code from Ben Bolker's website
predvar=diag(as.matrix(data.frame(a,b)) %*% vcov(mod)%*% t(as.matrix(data.frame(a,b))))
pred$fixed.SE=sqrt(predvar)
pred$fixed.SE2=sqrt(predvar+mod$sigma^2)

#Plot
ggplot()+geom_point(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y),col="grey50",alpha=0.5)+
  geom_line(data=subset(pred,max(df$x)>x & x>1),aes(x=x,y=fitted,group=entry),col="grey50")+
  geom_ribbon(data=subset(pred,max(df$x)>x & x>1),aes(x=x,ymin=fixed-2*fixed.SE,ymax=fixed+2*fixed.SE),alpha=0.5,fill="grey10")+
  geom_ribbon(data=subset(pred,max(df$x)>x & x>1),aes(x=x,ymin=fixed-2*fixed.SE2,ymax=fixed+2*fixed.SE2),alpha=0.3,fill="grey50")+
  geom_line(data=subset(pred,max(df$x)>x & x>1),aes(x=x,y=fixed),col="black",lwd=1.1)
```

The resulting plot looks like this, with the confidence band bouncing back and forth:

[image]

I suspect I have gone awry somewhere along the line (perhaps in the matrix multiplication?). Any help is appreciated, including suggestions on whether this is a good idea!

Comment: you can fix most of your plotting problems by adding `group=entry` to your aesthetics list for `geom_ribbon`.  (I would also recommend setting `predsub <- subset(pred,max(df$x)>x & x>1)` and substituting `data=predsub` rather than repeating all this stuff every time.)  However, this leads to giant confidence intervals on the `entry="a"` group, probably because your model is a bit weird/overfitted ...

Comment: (i.e. by weird/overfitted I mean the fact that you are treating `a` and `b` as random-effect parameters, varying at the level of `entry`, but there are only two levels of that grouping variable ...)

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for responding! I'm glad to know that the weird plot was not due to an error in the math (e.g., that I got the right design matrix, etc.). I'm afraid the simplified example data may have generated a wonky model, but for my real dataset, entry does indeed represent a random variable. Thanks for also not pointing out that I essentially fit a linear model when asking about non-linear ones ;). I'll go ahead and mark this as answered

Comment: if I have a chance I will post an answer based on my comment above.  Feel free to post one yourself, though.