# R: Quantifying uncertainty for predictions from lme4 (predict.merMod)

Tags: r, predict, lme4, statistics-bootstrap, simulate

I have the following mixed effects model with two crossed random effects which I am using to model tree growth:

```
Model <- lmer (log(Growth) ~ log(Size) + log(Competition) + (1 + log(Size) | Treatment) + (1 | Plot))
```

I am using this model to predict new data, and was glad to see that the development version of **lme4** now comes with a `predict` function that allows both fixed and random effects to be used to generate predictions. However I also need to be able to estimate the uncertainty in the predictions I am making, which is a problem since `predict` in **lme4** doesn't generate SE for predictions.

I have tried to alternative approached. The first was to use `simulate` to generate a distribution of predicted values which I could then summarize into uncertainty estimates. However, I found that the output of `simulate` is clearly different from that of `predict`, regardless of how I treated the use.u argument relating to random effects. When I take the mean predicted value across 1000 or more simulations and compare it to the output of `predict`, it is clear that the two methods are producing different results.

The second approach was to use the bootMer function as recommended in the help file for `predict`. From this I was able to obtain SE for the parameter estimates. However, I'm not quite sure how to then translate these into uncertainty in the predictions (i.e., how do I obtain SEs for the predicted values?). Am I missing something obvious?

Any help/advice on the two approaches I have used would be much appreciated, as would any suggestions on alternatives I have not considered!

Comment: It is not obvious to me what exactly you are predicting: Are you predicting for a specific treatment and a specific plot? Or for a specific treatment and the plot population? Possibly related: [Extract prediction band from lme fit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14435982/1412059) (including links and comments).

Comment: Sorry for not making it clearer: I want to be able to use the model to predict the growth of trees of a given size and competitive environment (fixed effects), and  growing in specific treatments and/or plots (random effects). Although `predict` will allow me to do this, for lmer models it will not provide SE for the predictions. I am trying to find a way to incorporate the uncertainty in the model into my predictions so that I can make meaningful comparisons.

Comment: this is cross-posted to the r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org mailing list http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.lme4.devel . I will probably answer there.

Comment: Sorry for cross-posting. The message I sent to r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org was not appearing correctly. Thanks for your help!