# confidence intervals around lines from glmer in lme4

Tags: r, glm, interaction, confidence-interval

I have spent a large amount of time trying to figure out how to generate a desired plot, and was wondering if any one can help. The plot is to illustrate an interaction between 'time' and 'group' on a binary response variable, which increases faster over time for 'group 2' than 'group 1'.  Below is a simplified version of what I need using simulated data. I have correctly got to the point of plotting a slope for each group (I think), but now want to plot a measure of confidence around each of these slopes.

```
#simulate 41 individuals, each occurring over a random number of days:
days.each<-sapply(sample(2:40,41,T),function(a)1:a)
thedata<-data.frame(day=unlist(days.each))

#add the individual id in:
thedata$id<-rep(1:41,sapply(days.each,length))

#9 of these individuals are in group 1, and 10 and in group 2:
thedata$group<-ifelse(thedata$id<20,1,2)

#with increasing 'day', the y increases. This relationship is stronger in individuals from group 2:
thedata$y<-(thedata$day*thedata$group)

#Also, some individuals have generally higher 'y' than others:
thedata$y<-thedata$y+rnorm(41,10,3)[thedata$id]

#the y is binomial:
thedata$y<-rbinom(nrow(thedata),1,thedata$y/max(thedata$y))

#change the group and id to class "factor"
thedata$id<-as.factor(thedata$id);thedata$group<-as.factor(thedata$group)

#run the full model:
library(lme4)
model <- glmer(formula=y ~ day*group+(1|id),family=binomial,data=thedata)


#to illustrate the interaction, plot one line for each group:
vals<-predict(model,re.form=NA,type ="response")

plot(y~day,data=thedata,type="n")
lines(sort(vals[thedata$group==1])~sort(thedata$day[thedata$group==1]),col="black")
lines(sort(vals[thedata$group==2])~sort(thedata$day[thedata$group==2]),col="purple")

#now add confidence around these slopes?
```

any help would be massively appreciated

edit:
Previous questions were based on fitting confidence around linear mixed models with a single predictor. This question is concerning confidence for each value of x1 from a generalized linear mixed model with binomial error structure which includes two independent variables and the interaction between them. If anyone can demonstrate how something similar to the blue bands from [Extract prediction band from lme fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358811/extract-prediction-band-from-lme-fit) could be added to my plot, that would be excellent.

Comment: see `Predictions and/or confidence (or prediction) intervals on predictions` in http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract prediction band from lme fit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358811/extract-prediction-band-from-lme-fit)

Comment: Hi @EDi, thank you for your suggestion. But, I don't think it is a duplicate, as the other question cannot be used to answer this one (at least not by someone like me). If you could, however, show why this is a duplicate, and exactly how the previous question could be used, that would be massively appreciated.