# Literature Citation for a Method Discussed Elsewhere

Tags: intervals, prediction, citations

Does anyone know of a good literature citation for the method of generating prediction intervals as described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358811/extract-prediction-band-from-lme-fit)

The method is also discussed on [Ben Bolker's github page](https://github.com/bbolker/mixedmodels-misc/blob/master/glmmFAQ.rmd):

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it explains some of the information in Chapter 10 of his book:

Bolker, B. M.: Ecological Models and Data in R, in, Princeton University Press, New Jersey, 2008.

[Book Link](http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/emdbook/index.html)